# Google App for business + OpenId + GoogleAPIs in Java GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm finding a lot of problems trying to develop a google app to place in the market, with OpenID and accesing some google apis like G+ from the backserver on GAE

I have applications running using google apis to acces G+ data, with 3 legged oAuth (code flow) without problems and i understand the "magic" behind the scenes, but i'm getting lost with OpenID and google market. Do i need to do the 3legged oAuth after the user pass the OpenID google filter, and send the user to acept the G+ permission API to use that token to access google apis? If this is the case, what happen if the user access the application from his company gmail account, and when prompted to accept the g+ access, he change accounts? Is there any good reading that make things easier with google apps, openID and access google apis from GAE?

Why I can't specify the scope of G+ when sending my application to the market, in the app conf files?

In this scenario, what is the best way of getting the user g+ profile (picture, fullname, nickname? What i'm missing? google documentation is really good, when you find the correct one ,but a lot of links are dead and millions of examples with deprecated gdata apis are flooding the net...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further reading and testing i came up with this points:

- Google Marketplace just alow you to access [this apis](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest?hl=es#supported_scopes) without extra "oAuth dances"
- If you want to access more APIs than the listed above, you need the oAuth exchange to get specific token/s for the APIs you want to access.
- In my case, i want to access G+ API before the openID from market, so after logging the user with openID, i need to redirect him to google api oAuth accept screen (just for the first time)

More things about the market that take me long time to catch:
- Billing API and license API are deprecated, this mean you are responsible for billing your users and keep them tracked to know if a given user has paid the application or when the license has expired
- You need to map /_ah/login_required becouse your application should be setted (when you create it) to only accept federated logins, wich will lead to a redirection to /_ah/login_required from where you need to do the openID stuff.

A lot of links in the documentation are broken and the examples are too old :(

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a little simpler now with the new Google Apps Marketplace experience. If you follow the steps in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing) and make sure you ask for the same scopes in your App Engine code, the user should never be prompted.